# zero out memory in .NET

Tags: .net, memory-management

Instead of just releasing the contents for GC, how can one zero out memory?

For example, if you have a custom DTO or a DataSet with sensitive data, how can you clear the contents instead of just setting the variable to null or calling Dispose()?  (Aside from manually setting each data item to 0 or "")

Comment: See [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx)

Comment: `For example, if you have a custom DTO or a DataSet with sensitive data, how can you clear the contents` ... well call `clear` function on your dataset like `DataSet.Tables.Clear()` OR `DataSet.Clear()`

Comment: How do you use SecureString when your DataTable or DataRow is filled with sensitive data after calling an sproc?

Answer (score 0):

> Aside from manually setting each data item to 0 or ""

Aside from that there is no way to do it.

It may be worse than you think, since the GC could be moving the object around memory at will, leaving uncleared versions in free memory.

Comment: Encrypting data within your data structures, as with SecureString mentioned in the comment above, is good.